# CSS Background gradient only taking up bottom of the page and not appearing in the background

Tags: html, css, background

I am using a web tool for building online ecommerce stores and am trying to use the developer tools to add a linear gradient to the background. I have gotten the linear gradient to appear at the bottom of the page but it is sitting on top of the website as opposed to being the "background". It moves up and down when scrolling like a banner would.

https://stores.inksoft.com/test_store_1/shop/home

```
<style> 
    body {position: 
    relative; 
    margin: 0;
    height: 700px;
    background: linear-gradient(217deg, rgba(255,0,0,.8), rgba(255,0,0,0) 70.71%),
            linear-gradient(127deg, rgba(0,255,0,.8), rgba(0,255,0,0) 70.71%),
            linear-gradient(336deg, rgba(0,0,255,.8), rgba(0,0,255,0) 70.71%);;;
    }
```

Comment: Please share your html too for reference

Comment: For this particular question, a screen shot is not enough for us to be able to help you. Ideally you would edit your question to include a working snippet. (A snippet is the Stack Overflow equivalent of a Codepen or a jsFiddle.) If you can't include a working snippet then include a link to your live website.

Answer (score 0):

try to put your content inside a div container and apply the css class.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(
      217deg,
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8),
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 70.71%
    ),
    linear-gradient(127deg, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 255, 0, 0) 70.71%),
    linear-gradient(336deg, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 255, 0) 70.71%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>aasas<br>
  </div>
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and it is still remaining at the bottom of the page. I edited my original post to provide a link to the website if that helps!